# Unable to use DDMS in Mac Sierra (10.12.5)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ddms

I am trying to run the Android Device Monitor (in Android Studio 2.3.3) but encountering an error.

The error is :

```
!SESSION 2017-07-16 08:09:16.099 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/smreehaan/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault -keyring /Users/smreehaan/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-07-16 08:09:16.700
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-07-16 08:09:16.704
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.
```

I have installed Java SE 6 and Java 8 both. See the following pics.

[image: Installed it]

Installed Java 8.

[image: Installed Java 8]

Getting this error when I run Android Device Monitor from Android Studio 2.3.3

[image]